# Else condition seems not working in go

Tags: mysql, go

I have a MySQL database with one value in it, a string: "192.168.0.1"

Here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

func checkErr(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "be:me@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/ipdb?charset=utf8")
    checkErr(err)

    ip := "'192.168.0.1'"
    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM Ip_ipdata WHERE ipHost=" + ip)
    fmt.Println("insert")
    if rows != nil {
        for rows.Next() {
            var id int
            var ip string
            err = rows.Scan(&id, &ip)
            checkErr(err)
            fmt.Println(id)
            fmt.Println(ip)
        }

    } else {
        fmt.Println("insert2")
        stmt, err2 := db.Prepare("INSERT Ip_ipdata SET ipHost=2")
        checkErr(err2)

        _, err3 := stmt.Exec(ip)
        checkErr(err3)
    }
    fmt.Println("end")
}
```

When I put `"'192.168.0.1'"` in `ip` it works and shows as expected.

But when I put `"'192.168.0.2'"` in `ip` the else statement isn't run and it just exits.

It didn't print "insert2"

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zpqkv.png)
[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4qMN.png)

Comment: Best guess is that you're still in the if block then. Have you checked the number of rows you're getting back?

Comment: Check the error value returned by `db.Query`. It is often the case that functions/methods return a zero valued object (or a pointer to it) in case of an error. In fact this is considered good practice.

Comment: @william.taylor.09 dam you're right thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should get used to using '?' placeholders in your sql to allow for proper escaping and prevent any potential SQL injection attacks.

You should always check the error in Go before using the returned value.

```
ip := "192.168.0.1"
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM Ip_ipdata WHERE ipHost=?", ip)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
// this will ensure that the DB connection gets put back into the pool
defer rows.Close()

for rows.Next() {
    // scan here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Rows` returned by Query will not be `nil` in the case of no results, it will be empty. Try something like this:

```
func main() {
    ...
    fmt.Println("insert")
    checkErr(err)
    defer rows.Close()
    var found bool
    for rows.Next() {
        found = true
        ...
    }

    if !found {
        fmt.Println("insert2")
        ...
    }
    fmt.Println("end")
}
```

Note that like @jmaloney said, more robust error handling is a must as is closing your `Rows` pointer.